# Access Shortcode in ajax code?

Tags: shortcode, ajax

I have some data which is pulled over using `ajax`. Data works all fine, however, I have some `shortcode` been used in the same data which doesn't display as expected.

It looks like `shortcode` function isn't available at the time of `ajax` call.

Could anyone please help with how I can have access to `shortcode` within `ajax`?

Unfortunately code isn't very straightforward to put here. I am using [Calendar](https://pippinsplugins.com/sugar-event-calendar-wordpress/) plugin to display Calendar. Then using [Tippy](http://croberts.me/projects/wordpress-plugins/tippy-for-wordpress/) shortcodes to display events within calendar to expand on mouseover.
Shortcode to display event with Tippy popup doesn't work when the calendar is updated (on hitting next month or year) using ajax. Because somehow when content is pulled out using ajax at that particular time shortcodes API isn't available.

Comment: Please post your code so we can help more.

Comment: @Laxmana: code isn't straightforward to copy here. I tried explaining the issue in question. Please check again

Comment: I see. Then it's a plugin matter and you should contact with the support of Calendar plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Here is the solution:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
    jQuery('.tippy').tippy({ position: "link", offsetx: 0, offsety: 10, closetext: "X", hidedelay: 700, showdelay: 100, calcpos: "parent", showspeed: 200, hidespeed: 200, target: "_blank", showtitle: true, hoverpopup: true, draggable: true, dragheader: true, multitip: false, autoshow: false, showheader: true, showclose: true, htmlentities: false });
});
```

Put this anywhere on the page. Put your own parameters inside, of course.  More info here:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/tippy-not-working-with-calendar-for-future-months-in-events-manager-extended?replies=3

- Brian

Comment: Welcome to WP.SE, Brian. About your answer: You know that `ajaxSuccess()` will run on _each and every_ single AJAX success and not only a specific one? I can only recommend that you narrow down where it should trigger and where not to avoid unexpected results. Btw, there's a WYSIWYG button for link styling. Well formatted answers normally get more upvotes.